# Work done by wind on a windmill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque

A windmill has a rotor attached to a 3-blade system, each weighing 5000kg and measuring 34m in length. How much torque does the wind have to provide to make sure that the 3-blade system rotates at 12 rpm constantly? Assume the wind has to do 1000Nm of work overcoming friction in the rotor.

1. I can see how torque is needed to overcome friction.
2. What I do not see is how torque is relevant when rpm is a constant (there is no angular acceleration). Is it friction that is reducing rpm so that the wind has to continuously supply torque to maintain it?
3. The other thing I am unsure about is whether I need to take into account the change in gravitational potential energy of the blades as they move from a lower height to a higher height. Is that the right way to look at it? If a change in gravitational potential energy is relevant, how can I calculate that given when one blade goes up another comes down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking this a bit. Assuming *steady state conditions* the power $P$ needed to keep the windmill turning over steadily is given simply by:

$$\boxed{P=\omega \tau}$$

where $\omega$ is the steady angular velocity $\big(\omega =\frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}t}\big)$ and $\tau$ the torque that has to be overcome to turn the windmill at constant $\omega$.

$P$ (in $\mathrm{Watt}$), in the absence of wasteful, non-conservative friction, is of course the **useful power** delivered by the windmill. *This is also the amount of energy conferred by the wind to the windmill.*

> The other thing I am unsure about is whether I need to take into
> account change in gravitational potential energy of the blades as they
> move from a lower height to a higher height.

No. Due to the constant turning there is no **net** change in the CoM of the system and thus no net change in the potential energy $\Delta U$ either.